# My first riddle ^^

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge, geography

> The place of magical emerald light,
>   Where penguins are often in sight;
>   Here, red beast is on alert,
>   But still, freely, the devils lurk.

Name the place. :)

Comment: Nice first riddle :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you in

> Tasmania?

The place of magical emerald light,

> You can see the Aurora Australis from Tasmania

Where penguins are often in sight;

> And it’s far enough south to see penguins too

Here, red beast is on alert,

> Maybe red kangaroos, which aren't native to Tasmania but can be found there? Or possibly the Tasmanian tiger, which was thought to be extinct...? Per OP, this is the Red Lion on the flag of Tasmania. Thanks!! :D

But still, freely, the devils lurk.

> Tasmanian devils

Comment: Damn! Was it that easy? :D Correct answer, +1, all is good, except the part with the red beast. Contrary to Tasmanian devils, this beast doesn't live in wild in Tasmania. Can you maybe get it?

Comment: @GileBrt second try for the red beast! Thanks very much! Devil + Geography is usually a good leader towards this answer personally, but I did enjoy the riddle! :D

Comment: Not really, but a nice guess. The red beast is referring to rot13(gur erq yvba ba gur synt bs Gnfznavn). Congrats on your solve! :)